# Rotina incluida na ThreadPool para rodar em "segundo plano" não deixa que a aplicação continue executando

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, thread, threadpool

Possuo o seguinte trecho de código em um método de minha aplicação ASP.NET MVC que trata de excluir os diretórios e seus arquivos.

```cs
// efetuo processos de remoção de arquivos do banco de dados
await Context.SaveChangesAsync();

var itens = diretorios.Select(x => new
{
    x.Id,
    x.AreaId
});

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x =>
{
    var directories = itens
        .Select(item => Configurations.Documents.PublicDirectory(item.Id, item.AreaId))
        .Where(Directory.Exists);

    foreach (var directory in directories)
    {
        try
        {
            Directory.Delete(directory, true);
        }
        catch
        {
            // Ignore                   
        }
    }
});

return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Esperava que ao efetuar o enfileiramento da rotina na `ThreadPool` e saindo desse método que o processamento da aplicação (continuidade) fosse ocorrer sem problemas.

Assim foi durante o debug e os testes, sem problemas.
Porém, já em meu servidor web a coisa trava.

O redirecionamento para a `Action` `Index` funciona, no entanto, na `Index` há uma requisição Ajax para voltar a listar os arquivos (esses nem mesmo são buscados em disco, mas sim no banco de dados).

Essa requisição não é finalizada enquanto, pelo o que consegui entender, essa rotina enfileirada na `ThreadPool` não termina. Ou seja, meu gif de carregamento fica aparecendo até que finalmente o processo termina e então os arquivos e diretórios são listados.

A aplicação não abre em nenhum outro browser enquanto o processo não termina..

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> O que estou fazendo de errado?

Usando uma região crítica gigantesca. Como possivelmente outras requisições fazem uso dela, as requisições (que, aliás, são *threads* também) ficam bloqueadas até que o processo termine. [É o Jantar dos Filósofos numa abordagem Web](http://www.revista-programar.info/artigos/threads-semaforos-e-deadlocks-o-jantar-dos-filosofos/).

Esta não considero que seja a melhor forma de fazer. Em aplicações ASP.NET MVC, a melhor forma de estabelecer este paralelismo que você quer é utilizando alguma biblioteca de agendamento, [como a Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/).

A Hangfire permite que você dispare a tarefa e o restante da aplicação não seja bloqueada. Alguns mecanismos de controle podem ser necessários para garantir que algum dado em região crítica não seja acessado enquanto a Hangfire trabalha.